# OneDrive C# sdk itemcollection limit at 200

Tags: c#, onedrive

I had a question if I can get more than 200 items in the response for the query below:

```
var drive = await _OneDriveClient
                          .Drive
                          .Root
                          .ItemWithPath(Path)
                          .Children
                          .Request()
                          .GetAsync();
 return drive;
```

It looks like the response is limited to 200 results even though there are more items in the folder searched. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var pageRequest = await _OneDriveClient
                          .Drive
                          .Root
                          .ItemWithPath(Path)
                          .Children
                          .Request();
while (pageRequest != null)
{
    var page = await pageRequest.GetAsync();
    // do some stuff
    pageRequest = pageRequest.NextPageRequest;
}
```

Take a look at the Collections documentation: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/collections.md#collections-in-the-onedrive-sdk-for-c

Comment: Thanks I will try this out when I get home and let you know.